# Capturing Post parameters by monitoring network traffic in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firebug, har, browsermob-proxy

I havebeen recently trying things to capture network traffic in my Selenium WebDriver tests.

I tried:
**Firebug+NetExport** :NetExport is not supported for my FF41.

**BrowserMobProx**y:Post data is captured but i guess it is encoded.

**Har Export Trigger** : Again i am getting Post data as encoded.

The post url which i need to capture looks like this:
"mysite.com//xyz/index.cfm?&did=someData&id=1234"(https is being used)

I am totally exhausted with the results.
Is there a way by which i can capture the post request url along with parameters?
Pls suggest on this.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Form data will indeed be encoded, presumably as `multipart/form-data`, but it certainly can be decoded. It's a bit harder work if you're not inside a web container, but the code exists.

Here are some links that should help you:

- API and example code from Apache Commons FileUpload: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.html
- [Library and examples of parsing multipart/form-data from inputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13457503/954442)
- [How to decode http POST data in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659522/how-to-decode-http-post-data-in-java)
- http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html

Although I haven't investigated how BrowserMob could help you directly, having not needed/used this myself, if you [look at the source](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=multipart%2Fform-data) there clearly is some support.